# Create folder in Home directory

Tags: macos, swift

I am trying to create a folder in swift. Following code shows my creation of folder

```
var error: NSError?

var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
var documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
var dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyFolder")

if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath)) {
    NSFileManager.defaultManager() .createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &error)
}
```

Right now I am able to create the folder under document directory. But I need to create the folder in the path `/Users/macuser/` . Structed at this point. Need help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [`NSHomeDirectory()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory) is what your looking for.

```
var error: NSError?

var homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory()
var dataPath = homeDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyFolder")

if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath)) {
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &error)
}
```

Or a bit more succinctly:

```
let dataPath = "\(NSHomeDirectory())/MyFolder"
```

Comment: I have another doubt.. Creating folder in home directory is okay but how to add that folder directory under the favourites in the Finder ??